# Write image as 32 bit per channel (128 bit per pixel) bitmap from .net

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, colors

I generate HDR images at runtime which I need to save in perfect quality (I'm chaining those images through multiple filters so I want to keep maximum fidelity each time to avoid too much quality loss).

I'm saving those with the bitmap class using the PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb, I found a 64 bit format too but no 128bit ones in the list (for 32 bit per channel X 4 channels).

What is the correct way to save an array of colors consisting of 4 float components with no loss? Any image format is fine as long as I can do it from .NET (third party libs are OK if built in doesn't support it).

I'm looking for a pure .net solution preferably (no wrappers around unmanaged code / unmanaged libs to interop to).

Comment: Inventing your own image format doesn't get you that far, you still have a need to actually *display* the image.  You ought to be looking at something like OpenEXR or shop for a library.

Comment: I'm not trying to invent my own format, just to store images in any existing format that support my prerequisites. As i mentioned i'm very fine with shoping for a library, it's even in my question while inventing my own format is not! Edit: note that i'm not even interested in displaying the image at all in my program, just saving it for further use that depends on the user, so it may just get imported into other HDR software further down the road, displaying it is out of scope for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ImageMagick (http://www.imagemagick.org/script/high-dynamic-range.php) supports HDR images.

You can use ImageMagick.NET (http://imagemagick.codeplex.com) as .NET bindings.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's my bad for not adding this (i'm working in .net so much that to be it's obvious, but reading the question it definately wasn't obvious), i'd like a pure managed solution, so a paid .net library is fine, but a wrapper around a library (even if it's free) isn't so much. However if no one can suggest a pure .net solution i'll note this as an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any pure .NET solutions that are as robust or good with image manipulation as ImageMagick.

Comment: Well i don't really need anything to do image manipulation, i generate the images (myself, in 3D rendering) and then i just want to save, not manipulate, so i'm basically looking for a solution that would allow me to do foreach var pixel in myfloatarray bla bla save bitmap to disk nothing more. It's ok if it has no other features.

Comment: I see. Since the OpenEXR format look here http://www.openexr.com/openexrfilelayout.pdf (or most image formats, really) are not very easy to read and write - they're most definitely not just a foreach, you might have to depend on a library. And most libraries that handle loading or saving of specialized image formats most likely do something with it. So I don't know if you will find anything as specialized as what you need (HDR + fully managed + only saving). Especially if its commercial - such a targeted product would not really sell very much.

Comment: I see, i'll check if exr does it for me, thanks for the answers!